# The field is filled in correctly, but after a second it becomes empty, since some other postmessage comes again with undefined

Tags: javascript

**On the page where the iframe is inserted**

```
 var data = {mails: 'mymail@gmail.com'}; 
 setTimeout( function(){     
 iframe.postMessage(data,'*');
 }, 3000);
```

**PARENT**

```
   window.addEventListener('message', function(msg) {
     jQuery("#iframe-mail_owner").val(msg.data.mails);
      console.log(msg.data.mails); 

    });
```

[image]

The field is filled in correctly, but after a second it becomes empty, since some other postmessage comes again with undefined
And it's strange why I see recaptcha and other data in the logs, I made it clear that I output console.log(**e.data.mails**); not just DATA

Comment: Do you have any other code that's sending messages to that iframe?

Comment: I don't have any other code.this happens after recaptchacompat , this can be seen in the screenshot in the description

Comment: If you have no other code, nothing would be happening... You can log the `msg` variable to see what other messages are being sent. Something is sending other messages in a different format, it could just be code on the page loaded in the iframe.